# Most minimal solution to enlarge child so as to create scrollable space

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize, scroll

In html if a child div is bigger than the parent div it will create scrollbars on the parent div if you set the appropriate style rules.

However, I want it so that when an *attempt* to scroll occurs (by hitting the arrow keys, making the appropriate javascript call on the element) the minimum needed expansion in size occurs on the child occurs such that it can scroll to the degree that it would have scrolled anyway if the child was already that big.

To state that again: if the child was 300px width within a parent of 200px width, and I hit right arrow key, and it scrolls 20 pixels to the right, then if the child is 200px in that same scenario, I want it to enlarge in width by 20 pixels and no more if possible, and then scroll 20 pixels to the right.

This is all assuming there is no way to make a sub-element scroll within its parents regardless of whether it's actually larger than its parent.  There might well be so I apologise in advance if i haven't done enough research. :)

Comment: So you want the child elements to grow bigger as the user scrolls? Oh and if you haven't done enough research then you should be doing that.

Comment: @JCOC611 I don't want them to merely grow bigger-- I want them to grow only as large as they have to to allow scrolling to occur by the scrolling distance it would have used if the child element was larger than the max scrolling distance.

I didn't say I haven't done enough research, I said I may have not.  One can't know what one doesn't know they don't know.  Beside which, this site has no reason to exist if the answer is always 'do more research'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably know that the style `overflow: scroll` will make scroll bars show up regardless of child size. Do you actually need Javascript to boost the child dimensions, rather than having an extra wrapper div with greater dimensions that would cause the scroll like in [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gFTeG/10/)? I know Safari already scrolls approximately 20px on arrow key down within selected scroll divs by default, and I would assume other browsers have this functionality as well.

If you do have need for increasing the div size with javascript, jQuery has a few functions that would be helpful. The [.keydown() method](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) looking for left and right arrow keys (which I believe are key codes 37 and 39 respectively) and the [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) or some other [CSS method](http://api.jquery.com/category/css/) would work to resize the div chained together.

The [.scroll() method](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) could come in useful as well. You could chain the resize code to the scroll method with an `overflow: scroll` property already applied. I would test to see if browsers will trigger the .scroll method even if the scroll bars are empty. If not, you could potentially make the child only 1px wider/taller then the parent div and then rely on the jQuery to further resize on the user's scroll.

Broadly speaking, I would advise against the javascript/jQuery resize and scroll. Compatibility with different browsers, especially mobile browsers, would be inconsistent or unusable. I don't know exactly what your needs are, but if it can be accomplished with only HTML/CSS it would be much cleaner and more compatible. I would reserve the javascript for cases where usability will not be lost if it does not run.

Comment: The size is not predictable as the child can resize.  I can enlarge things enough in anticipation of scrolling that may occur, but ideally that's not what I want to have.  And that is how I have been doing it so far.

What kind of compatibility issues would arise from scrolling something, especially on a mobile device?  I thought standards were designed to prevent these inconsistencies.  Can you give specific examples?

Comment: Well a left/right arrow key press will obviously not work with a mobile device. You cannot always assume javascript will be run for a user (disabled, old IE, etc), but if that doesn't matter to you then by all means use it. Example: Usability would likely suffer from a javascript-operated scroll rather than a normal, smooth scroll in mobile safari. If the child can resize, couldn't you have a consistent wrapper class for scrolling? I guess I don't see why you'd need to resize through javascript when you can keep the div's size consistent with the wrapper or autosize by default.

Comment: I have a page where clicking on one the child elements of the 'container' div causes the entire contents of the container to be moved such that the clicked element is moved to the top left corner of the container.  I cannot predict how right-adjusted a given node might end up being, and it appears impossible to scroll if there isn't a scroll-bar even when forcing it from js (correct me if i'm wrong).  I can either enlarge the child container enough for any horizontal scrolling that may need to occur, or otherwise the javascript has to resize dynamically before it can scroll anywhere

Comment: Anyway, I feel you've answered enough of my question that I know where to go from here, thx.

Comment: Sounds like a complicated case. Glad I could be of some assistance.